# Can models disregard all entries with 'deleted' attribute = 1 in ActiveRecord?

Tags: yii2

I have a model called Document, and in this model I've overridden the `delete()`function to just update the attribute `deleted` to 1.

This model is in the middle of a web of relations. It belongs to one or more DocumentCategory, and it has one or more versions of DocumentFile, so I would like to disregard all deleted rows without having to write `->where(['deleted' => 0])` in all my relational queries.

How can I solve this fast and yii-like?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['deleted' => 0]);
}
```

So when you call your `Document::find()->all()` for example where will be added.
But its not good idea to owerwrite find like this, better make function called `findActive()` with same contents and use it `Document::findActive()->all()`.

Comment: Nice one for all the find() functions, but it does not work for relations where the document are joined in. Like `DocumentCategory::find()->with('documents')->all();`

Comment: add where in `getDocuments()`, it's not a big deal)

Comment: Yeah, but i also have it connected to a notification system and a logging system. I could do it for all of them, but i was hoping it was a more permanent solution.

Comment: This solution also removes the possibility to add a new where clause, as this will override the where from the find() override. Might be a good solution for some people, but it will not work in my problem.

Comment: How about create a new parent `ActiveRecord` and override the `find`, and all models extends that `ActiveRecord` instead?